# When I import a CSV file with data that I have not enteredd manually into my CSV file, I am not able to import into PGAmin4 successfully

Tags: csv, import, pgadmin-4

When I import a relatively simple CSV file where I have inputted/typed the data manually, I am able to import the data through the Import / Export function in PgAdmin 4 without a problem. I do it the same way I was taught in a SQL Bootcamp course, i.e., create a new database. Then create a table with the respective columns and assign its constraints eg admin_id INT PRIMARY KEY, etc, etc.

Then when I try to import the same file that has copied information  i.e. info I have not manually typed into the CSV file then it creates an error:

ERROR invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8" 0xa0

CONTEXT: COPY bikefactory, line

This is really weird. Has anyone else encountered this?

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Kind regards,

Barney

Comment: You probably need to set the encoding. Every text file has an encoding (such as utf-8, utf-16, ISO-8859-1, Latin1 etc etc). Have you tried a different encoding? Have you tried to verify the actual encoding of your csv file?

Comment: @topsail Thank you very much! I saved as CSV UTF 8 and it worked like a charm! You are a life saver!